# unbalanced parenthesis : Local Play 2.0.3

Tags: scala, playframework

I've looked around for some time and have not found anything like this, I assume it's a version mismatch. I also tried to require: -play 2.0.3 and get:

```
-----> Installing Play! 2.0.3.....
-----> Error installing Play! framework or unsupported Play! framework version     specified. Please review Dev Center for a list of supported versions.
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play! app
```

Sounds weird? I looked at Dev Center and it supposed to be supported.

Here is my deployment error with play! 1.2.4 as default

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
`012-08-27T08:42:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `play run --        http.port=24193 --%prod -Dprecompiled=true`
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]: CompilerOracle: exclude     jregex/Pretokenizer.next
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 08:42:07,856 INFO  ~ Starting /app
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 08:42:07,943 INFO  ~ Application is precompiled
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.Play.start(Play.java:556)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.Play.init(Play.java:300)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:159)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:374)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:308)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: jregex.PatternSyntaxException: unbalanced parenthesis
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:206)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:219)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Pattern.<init>(jregex/Pattern.java:150)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Pattern.compile(jregex/Pattern.java:164)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at jregex.Pattern.<init>(jregex/Pattern.java:108)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router$Route.compute(Router.java:715)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router.getRoute(Router.java:134)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router.appendRoute(Router.java:118)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:199)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:164)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router.load(Router.java:48)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.Play.start(Play.java:519)
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 2 more
2012-08-27T08:42:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Router.detectChanges(Router.java:219)
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ |_|            |__/   
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ framework ID is prod
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ play! 1.2.5, http://www.playframework.org
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~        _            _ 
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ Ctrl+C to stop
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~
2012-08-27T08:42:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ~ 
2012-08-27T08:42:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-27T08:42:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

-------------------------------------------
shell# heroku ps
=== web: `play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS`
web.1: crashed for 9m
```

Edit: ---- Routes File

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# The home page
GET     /                                   controllers.Projects.index

# Authentication
GET     /login                              controllers.Application.login
POST    /login                              controllers.Application.authenticate
GET     /logout                             controllers.Application.logout

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /public path
GET     /assets/*file                       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: Seems like an error in your routes file, please post that file.

Comment: I am confused why you are using Play 1.2.5 and Play 2.0.3...which one are you using??

Comment: Routes file added above -- I am building locally on play 2.0.3 and the app works correctly, and when I deploy Heroku won't let me install the needed version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: For some reason project/ was in .gitignore which was causing this error. Not very verbose to the issue.